# Fail when delete optional tag from soap request

Tags: java, spring, soap, xsd, spring-ws

As suggested in title I have an error when i delete optional parameter from request

Full request:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v001="http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v001:Request>
         <v001:locationId>lyuda_0309001_loc</v001:locationId>
         <v001:workOrderId>88155530</v001:workOrderId>
         <v001:systemName>NINAS</v001:systemName>
         <v001:scenarioId>2</v001:scenarioId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v001:scenarioData>
            <v001:scenarioData></v001:scenarioData>
         </v001:scenarioData>
      </v001:Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When i call it with

```
             <v001:scenarioData>
                <v001:scenarioData></v001:scenarioData>
             </v001:scenarioData>
```

everything is ok 
but when i try to delete optional tag

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v001="http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v001:NinasNCOssRequest>
         <v001:locationId>lyuda_0309001_loc</v001:locationId>
         <v001:workOrderId>88155531</v001:workOrderId>
         <v001:systemName>NINAS</v001:systemName>
         <v001:scenarioId>2</v001:scenarioId>
      </v001:NinasNCOssRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and make a call i've got a fault:

```
<Error> <org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher> <devapp104.netcracker.com> <clust1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <guest> <> <> <1442316335622> <BEA-000000> <ERROR org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher - EndpointInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault"). Expected elements are <{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}Request>,<{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}Response>,<{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}ScenarioEnum>,<{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}ValidationException>
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:863)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:742)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:720)
    at com.net.tel.interceptors.AttachmentInterceptor.afterCompletion(AttachmentInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.afterCompletion(DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.triggerAfterCompletion(MessageDispatcher.java:399)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:239)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3732)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault"). Expected elements are <{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}Request>,<{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}Response>,<{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}ScenarioEnum>,<{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}ValidationException>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:663)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1064)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:499)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:480)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:305)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:127)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:738)
    ... 27 more
>
```

xsd schema of request:

```
<xsd:element name="NinasNCOssRequest" type="RequestType"/>

<xsd:complexType name="RequestType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="locationId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"/>
            <xsd:element name="workOrderId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"/>
            <xsd:element name="systemName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"/>
            <xsd:element name="scenarioId" type="schema:ScenarioType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"/>
            <xsd:element name="scenarioData" type="schema:ScenarioDataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="ScenarioType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
            <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="ScenarioDataType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="scenarioData" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Any hints how to solve it?

Comment: Add the request you are sending... The one that doesn't work

Comment: Those are completely different requests, with a different namespace... etc. The request that fails has `xmlns:v001="http://xmlns.telenet.be/oss/ninas/v001"` the one that is ok has `xmlns:v001="http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001"` Also your start tag is different. Seems like you are mixing things up

Comment: sorry for that, when i added question after your comment i forgot to change paths :) now everything should be ok

Comment: Can you show the accompanying relevant part of the XSD that defines that element (it's not just a tag) as optional?

Comment: @Abel updated  the question

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I thought you had a validation exception, hence I asked about your XSD schema file. However, this turns to be incorrect.

You showed:

```
<Error> <org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher> <devapp104.netcracker.com> <clust1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <guest> <> <> <1442316335622> <BEA-000000> <ERROR org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher - EndpointInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault"). Expected elements are <{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}Request>,<{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}Response>,<{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}ScenarioEnum>,<{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}ValidationException>
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:863)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:742)
```

The important part is this:

```
nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: 
unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault"). 
Expected elements are 
    <{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}Request>,
    <{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}Response>,
    <{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}ScenarioEnum>,
    <{http://xmlns.tel.be/nin/v001}ValidationException>
```

The `<Fault>` that you receive does not mean that the XML you sent is incorrect, but that the receiving end did not expect the data. Service implementations of SOAP send it when something unexpected happens, for instance an uncaught exception on the receiving end.

To found out what is causing the exception, you should ask the receiving end to implement SoapFaultDetail. Once you have that, and they fill it with more details (like a stacktrace or actual error), you can investigate that better. [Here's a guide on how to do that with Spring](http://www.stevideter.com/2009/02/18/of-exceptionresolvers-and-xmlbeans/).

Of course, you could also just ask them why they don't send you a proper response, even though you stuck to the XSD design.

Comment: thanks for advice, I'll try to investigate this problem with SoapFaultDetail

Answer (score 0):

The exception primarily indicates that there is a problem in the implementation of `com.net.tel.interceptors.AttachmentInterceptor`. The stack trace indicates that this is an endpoint interceptor that attempts to do some postprocessing on the response from the service, but fails to recognize SOAP fault responses: instead of handling them differently, it just tries to unmarshal the payload as in the same way as for a successful response, resulting in an exception that hides the original SOAP fault.

Once you fix that problem in `com.net.tel.interceptors.AttachmentInterceptor` you will get a meaningful SOAP fault response that will likely give you an indication why the service rejected your request.